# Property 'form' does not exist on type 'ControlGroup, when implementing TinyMCE editor

Tags: angular

I followed the Plunker example to consume the TinyMCE editor, however, I got errors when I tried to compile my Angular 2 typescripts project.

I posted the relevant section of the code below.

Alternatively you can check out [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ryvhsn3goOw5bPbrEnom?p=preview) for details.

```
import {ElementRef, Directive, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlGroup, Control} from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  inputs: ['tinyMce'],
  selector: '[tinyMce]'
})
export class TinyEditor {
  public tinyMce: ControlGroup;
  private zone: NgZone;
  private id: string = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
  private controlName: string;
  private theControl: Control;

  public constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private zone: NgZone) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.controlName = this.elRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('ngControl');
      this.theControl = this.tinyMce.form.controls[this.controlName];
    });
    this.elRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('tiny-id', this.id);
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      tinymce.init({
        valid_elements: '*[*]',
        selector: '[tiny-id=' + this.id + ']',
        schema: 'html5',
        height: 400,
        setup: (editor): void => {
          editor.on('keyup change', () => {
            this.zone.run(() => {
              let value: Object = editor.getContent();
              this.theControl.updateValue(value, {emitEvent: true});
              this.theControl.markAsDirty();
              this.theControl.markAsTouched();
              this.theControl.updateValueAndValidity();
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    try {
      tinymce.remove('[tiny-id=' + this.id + ']');
    } catch(e) {
      console.error('Error:', e);
    }
  }
}
```

Errors as below:

1. Property 'form' does not exist on type 'ControlGroup.
2. tinymce not found.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Answers:  1. Replace the code with this line of code. **this.theControl = this.tinyMce.controls[this.controlName]** ;    2. Place new line of code. **declare var tinymce: any**. Replace these codes in the tiny-editor.ts. Hope this is helps.

Comment: You made a similar post like 1 hour ago, where you just put a blogpost-like 'question' with the answer contained in it

Comment: I was told that, I could just create a question and answer it by myself. Well, actually I just wanted to share out this solution. Please advise what should I do? I am new StackOverFlow. Your advice much appreciated. The previous post I have deleted.

Comment: that is indeed the normal approach, but you posted this as a *comment*. Please use the "answer" section below :-)

Comment: Bravo! @DylanMeeus   Thank you so much for your kind advice. :-)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have spent many hours try to figure out the solution, how to implement the TinyMCE editor in Web Application in Angular 2 RC and TypeScripts. I got the Plunker's link from one of the blogs, and I gave a try but with errors. When I implement the tiny-editor.ts in my project and compile, I got errors Property 'form' does not exist on type 'ControlGroup. I fixed it.

Here is the fixed code and steps.

1. Integrate the TinyMce assembly files. You can directly call from official API link or download the package from NPM or Bower to your local machine project.

   2. Place the tiny-editor.ts in your shared folder, anyway in your project folder.
   3. Please include the tiny-editor.ts into your correspondence components that you want to show the editor. Please ! DO NOT FORGET the Directives, in your component files.
      Lastly, place the html tag in your HTML file .

Here you go the Fixed version. I tried and it works like a champ.
PLEASE MKE GREEN TICK,IF THIS HELPS FOR YOU!

Happy coding! :)

```
import {ElementRef, Directive, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlGroup, Control} from '@angular/common';

declare var tinymce: any;
@Directive({
  inputs: ['tinyMce'],
  selector: '[tinyMce]'
})
export class TinyEditor {
  public tinyMce: ControlGroup;

  private id: string = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
  private controlName: string;
  private theControl: any;

  public constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private zone: NgZone) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.controlName = this.elRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('ngControl');
      this.theControl = this.tinyMce.controls[this.controlName];
    });
    this.elRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('tiny-id', this.id);
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      tinymce.init({
        valid_elements: '*[*]',
        selector: '[tiny-id=' + this.id + ']',
        schema: 'html5',
        height: 150,
        language : "en", // change language here
        setup: (editor): void => {
          editor.on('keyup change', () => {
            this.zone.run(() => {
              let value: Object = editor.getContent();
              this.theControl.updateValue(value, {emitEvent: true});
              this.theControl.markAsDirty();
              this.theControl.markAsTouched();
              this.theControl.updateValueAndValidity();
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    try {
      tinymce.remove('[tiny-id=' + this.id + ']');
    } catch(e) {
      console.error('Error:', e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We can not use the "green tick", that means it is the correct answer and only the original person who asked it (you in this case) can do that. You have my upvote though ;-)

Comment: I just tried. It says I can only try in 2 days .. :P. I hope this fixed helps. :P!